# How to show html in textview with dynamic height?

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

My problem is that I have done to show html in `textview` but problem  appear in this that `textview` height not perfectly set and also try with  web view same problem appear.

How to render text in `textview` with dynamic height ?

Please help me out.

Comment: what problem you faced exactly ?

Comment: Q. No. : 5<p>कोलकाता। कांग्रेस की पश्चिम बंगाल इकाई पार्टी हाईकमान से नाराज चल रही है और इसकी वजह यह है कि पार्टी में शीर्ष स्तर पर उनकी राय को महत्व नहीं दिया जा रहा। बंगाल इकाई का मानना है कि कांग्रेस नेतृत्व और</p>
<p>ग्रेस चुनावों में मिली रही लगातार हार और पार्टी का दामन छोड़ कर जाते &nbsp;c</p>

Comment: this is my html and get from server and im showing this in textview but textview not perfectly create text height wise in ios 
im using nsattributestring like and heights estimate
 NSAttributedString *texts=[self attribute:htmfile];
    
    CGRect requiredSize = [texts boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){qsview.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX} options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading
     context:nil];

Comment: can you share screen shot which kind of issue you faced ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `UIWebView` instead.
Implement the `UIWebViewDelegate`, where `webViewDidFinishLoad` should look like this:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
     webView.frame.size.height = 1
     webView.frame.size = webView.sizeThatFits(CGSize.zero)
     //layout any other elements in the view if needed
}
```

Do not forget to set the webview's delegate.

Comment: im using objective-c my webview size not extend properly height pls help me

Comment: if you are using objecitve-c:
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    CGRect frame = webView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    webView.frame = frame;
    CGSize size = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = size;
    webView.frame = frame;
}

Comment: this is done now i need to add two webview one in section and another in cell in table view how get every webview height for table section height and row.